# MAGOO 2-Point Correlation function derivation

Tags: correlation-functions, ads-cft, supergravity

I am studying the famous [MAGOO](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905111) review and I am trying to understand section 3.3 where we calculate the correlation functions from the AdS side. In subsection 3.3.1 the authors go through the 2-point functions.

The given action is
$$
S=\frac{\eta}{2}\int{d^5x\sqrt{g}\left[(\partial\phi)^2+m^2\phi^2\right]}
$$
where we used the Euclidean action and the metric is given in Poincare coordinates as
$$
ds^2=\frac{R^2}{z^2}(dx^2+dz^2)
$$
again, where $dx^2$ is the Euclidean part of the metric and $dz^2$ gives the radial part of AdS space. Then the fields are expressed in Bessel functions as
$$
\phi(x,z)=\frac{z^2K_{\Delta-2}(pz)}{\epsilon^2K_{\Delta-2}(p\epsilon)}e^{ipx}
$$
Where $K_{\Delta-2}(pz)$ is the  modified Bessel function of the second kind. My problem is in deriving equation (3.40) where we substitute the field in the action and then compute the integral. Do we first take the limit of the Bessel function with $z\rightarrow0$ and then do the integration?

My attempt:
$$
S= \frac{\eta}{2}\int{d^4xdz\left[\frac{R^3}{z^3}(\nabla\phi)^2+\frac{R^3}{z^3}(\partial_z\phi)^2+\frac{R^5}{z^5}m^2\phi^2\right]}
$$
then if I substitute $\phi$ everything is a mess. I have also took the limit of the field for $z\rightarrow0$ giving
$$
\phi(z\rightarrow 0)\rightarrow\frac{\Gamma(\Delta-2)e^{ipx}}{2\epsilon^2K_{\Delta-2}(p\epsilon)}\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^{2-\Delta}z^{4-\Delta}
$$

**My progress**

So far I have used the fact that the derivative of the specific bessel function has the following closed form
$$
\partial_z K_\nu(pz) = \frac{\nu}{z}K_{\nu}(pz)-pK_{\nu+1}(pz)
$$
then carefully taking the derivatives and collecting the terms I computed the following integral
$$
S = \frac{\eta}{2\epsilon^4 K^2_{\Delta-2}(p\epsilon)}\int{d^4x dz e^{2ipx}\left[-p^2R^3 z K^2_{\Delta-2}(pz)+R^3\left(\Delta^2 K^2_{\Delta-2}(pz)+p^2 z K^2_{\Delta-1}(pz)-2\Delta p K_{\Delta-2}(pz)K_{\Delta-1}(pz)\right)+R^5 m^2 z^{-1}K^2_{\Delta-2}(pz)\right]}
$$
Now each integral in $z$ indeed has the form $\int{dz z^n K^2_{\nu}(pz)}$. Then we note that the $z$ integral is in the range $(\epsilon,\infty)$. I understand that we should take this integral and then expand in $\epsilon$ but I am not sure how to compute the integral.

Comment: I don't think you can take the limit $z\rightarrow 0$ since you are integrating over $z$. But I'm not sure you should get a mess. The form for $\phi$ is basically $\phi(x,z) = C F(z) e^{i p x}$, for a constant $C$, and where $F(z) = z^2 K_{\Delta - 2}(pz)$. The $x$ integrals should all give you things like delta functions or derivatives of delta functions. The $z$ integrals should all have the form of $\int z^n K_{m}^2(z)$ (note you can use properties of Bessel functions to replace derivatives of Bessel functions with sums of Bessel functions). I bet you can do these on mathematica (...)

Comment: (...) and at least get an answer in terms of hypergeometric functions. Then to get something simple, you will need to expand the result in small $\epsilon$ as they say in the paper.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew! How do we tackle the integrals over the Bessel functions though?

Comment: Have you tried mathematica?

Comment: I don't have mathematica but I found some answers for that integral on Wolfram

Comment: Great! I'd guess you will get some special functions like hypergeometric functions, but you should be able to expand these for small epsilon (hopefully Wolfram Alpha can do that)

Comment: Admitetly, I wasn't able to find the special functions you mentioned. Do you have any resources on this yourself? My problem is in the evaluation of the $\int{dz}\;z^n K_m(pz)^2$ type integrals.

Comment: @twistedmanifold In Mma `v12` if you execute `Integrate[z^n BesselK[m, p z]^2, z] // FullSimplify` you get the following result - see next comment as it is too long to be put here

Comment: ``1/8 \[Pi]^(3/2) z^(1 + n) (p z)^(-2 m)
  Csc[m \[Pi]]^2 (-2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] (p z)^(2 m)
     Gamma[(1 + n)/
     2] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, (1 + n)/2}, {1 - m, 
      1 + m, (3 + n)/2}, p^2 z^2] + 
   Gamma[1/2 - m] Gamma[
     1/2 (1 - 2 m + n)] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2 - m, 
      1/2 (1 - 2 m + n)}, {1 - 2 m, 1 - m, 1/2 (3 - 2 m + n)}, 
     p^2 z^2] + (p z)^(4 m)
     Gamma[1/2 + m] Gamma[
     1/2 + m + n/2] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2 + m, 
      1/2 + m + n/2}, {1 + m, 1 + 2 m, 3/2 + m + n/2}, p^2 z^2])``

Comment: Note that no assumptions were used and this is the most general result for the indefinite integral